# Set of all points having the same distance from a fixed point and a line in space

Tags: geometry, 3d

We all know the definition of a parabola, set of all points in a plane which have the same distance from an specific point and a *line*.

If we expand the idea to 3 dimensions we will see a **paraboloid** which is the set of all points having the same distance from an specific point and a *plane* here is what i mean https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Paraboloid_of_Revolution.svg

So my question is what is the shape of all points having the same distance from an specific point and a *line* in space (3 dimensions)?

The answer to my question may be an equation of such a shape or simply an image, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the point be $F = (0, p, 0) $ and the line  $L: (0, -p, 0) + t (1, 0, 0) $

Distance squared from the point P to the given point F is

$ PF^2 = x^2 + (y - p)^2 + z^2 $

Distance squared from point P to the line is

$ PL^2 = (x^2 + (y + p)^2 + z^2) - ( (x, y+p, z) \cdot (1, 0, 0) )^2$

which simplifies to

$ PL^2 = (y + p)^2 + z^2$

Hence the desired equation is obtained by setting $ PF^2 = PL^2 $ which gives

$ x^2 + (y - p)^2 = (y + p)^2 $

which simplifies to

$ x^2 - 2 p y = 2 p y $

i.e.

$ 4 p y = x^2 $

and this the equation of a parabolic sheet (as $z$ can assume any value).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are describing a **parabolic cylinder** where the focus (point) is above the curve and the directrix (line) runs perpendicular to the "spine" of the cylinder.

[image]